# Buttons not down-scaling with images?

Tags: html, css, image, imagebutton

I have a 200px*200px `<img>` in a `<button>` on my page. If I down-scale the image using CSS :

```
img{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
```

, button still remains huge, as if the image was still full sized.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: transform:scale(x); only resize at screen, element still uses its original room/space

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
        img {
          width: 50%;
          height: auto;
        }
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: It's still the same, the button is still the original size of the image (+ some padding of course).

Comment: I did it same as you. May it be due to the fact that I use Bootstrap?

Comment: Take a look at this. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpgbpJ
The button is still wide. Even though I scaled down the image. That's the same problem that I have. @guvenckardas

Comment: maybe you should use an input type="image" and resize this input :) (not rescale) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyPoym